# Blank page for 5sec while using requirejs with AMD

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, requirejs, angular-amd

I have run into an strange issue recently while using requirejs and AngularAMD for asynchronously loading modules. The site is loading perfectly but there is a blank white page for about 5 seconds(random time as i have too many dependencies) until all the dependencies are loaded by requirejs.

The browser pre-loader is also hidden and blank page is displayed, and after about 5 seconds, whoosh all content is visible.

Comment: Does all these dependencies need to load before the first partial can be inserted? Can't help you unless you share the code to reproduce the issue...

Comment: @TJ, it's a simple angularAMD app, have followed this example: https://bl.ocks.org/marcoslin/df4b741e92b2829eeae8

Comment: That is a simple example. What I'm asking is how you're doing it. Do you have all the dependencies listed in the main app module?

Comment: yeah, all the dependencies are listed in requires's config (main) and using angularAMD.route for lazy loading controllers for requested routes

Comment: Nope, I'm asking how you have distributed your apps dependencies. all of them are listed in the app.js file? (where you declare your app module and define routes in the example)

Comment: nope, not all, only dependencies required for module definition are listed there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109057/discussion-between-icanbeacoder-and-t-j).